# Reset all HttpApplication instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule, isapi, httpapplication

I have defined and assigned HTTP module with data that are initialized once, when module was created.
During the work of asp.net application I would like to say - Reset this data on all instances of that module type.
As you know there is HttpApplication pool managed by Asp.Net and modules collection for each Asp.Net application instance. I would like to have possibility from some admin .aspx page to say - Reset all HTTP modules. I know only how to catch/access active HTTP application instance and HTTP module instance for current HTTP request. How to do that for all module instances. Is is possible to access global HttpApplication pool or is there some other pattern for this issue ?

Comment: It is a weird question, as if the module is written by you you can keep track of them and easily reset them using something like Publisher pattern. If the module is not yours, unload the app domain can trigger a full reload, which also reset the data.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented on my way. Each initialized module is subscribed to some global event. That is possible. I was just wondered is there some built in mechanism to use instead of custom solution.